# datamigration from datefield to datetimefield

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm just wondering where/what did I do wrong. So here's the scenario.

I have a field `date = DateField()` then I want to change it to d`ate = DateTimeField()` without losing the data stored from it.

What I did:

- Add temporary field `temp = DatetimeField()` then transfer the value from `date = DateField()` to temp by datamigration
- remove `date = DateField()`
- Add `date = DateTimeField()`
- Transfer stored value from `temp` to `date`

Everything went great, no errors. But one thing changed, `the value`.

For example:

Old data: `datetime.date(2014, 5, 5)`

New data: `datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 4, 12, 0, tzinfo=UTC)`

So my question is, why did it changed and `deduct 1` day from the original value? Any thoughts? Is it because of the timezone? Timezone was set to `Pacific/Auckland`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The GMT offset for Pacific/Auckland is **UTC+12** (hours).

`datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 4, 12, 0, tzinfo=UTC)` represents noon UTC **on the 4th**. But due to the offet, this is midnight in Auckland. However, midnight in Auckland is in fact "hour 0" **on the 5th**.

So, yes, the issue does have to do with timezones, but it's in fact not an issue. The date didn't change, it's just expressed in a different timezone.

---

Naturally, you could rollback the migration, and you account for timezones differently in step 1 where you transform the `date` into a `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you. What's your suggestion or steps to be done in order not to lose the original date value?